# Send to Ms SharePoint

Tags: cognito-forms, sharepoint

I cannot find a setting to populate results to a SharePoint list, please help. I thought this was because I was on the trial version but even after subscribing to the $24 plan a month I still cannot see the option.

Another thing, I have exported the results from the Cognito Forms to Excel and got the column names that I have used on the SharePoint list - I hope this is the correct way.

Comment: I have managed to get it working by going to design mode, clicking on the "Submit" button and edit its settings/properties. I have also modified the SharePoint list columns to reflect the field labels but the problem is e.g. I have "Name" field in 3 sections (Company Contact, Student, and Parent) and when it comes to SharePoint I can only name one column like that. Also, some columns do not populate to SharePoint even though they are the only ones on the form.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

You can connect your Cognito Form to Microsoft SharePoint. This can be done in the Submission Settings on the Build page of the form your looking to connect. You can learn more about this process in our [Help Content](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/64/data-integration/microsoft-sharepoint).

If you are using fields that has duplicate titles even if they are in different Sections, only one field will be brought over into SharePoint. This means that if you have the Name field titled 'Name' in 2 different Sections, Student and Parent, only the last Name field will be brought over into SharePoint when the form is submitted.

You will also need to create your columns, in your list by editing the list and adding the column. If you use the 'quick edit' feature in SharePoint, the column will not be populated.